# How to restart HDFS on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, emr

I have made some changes in the settings for HDFS on an Amazon EMR cluster. I want to restart the namenode and the datanode for the changes to take effect. I am not able to find any start and stop scripts to do so on neither the namenode(master) nor the datanodes. What should be the way to restart the cluster?

Answer (score 3):

On EMR4 , run following on master host -

```
sudo /sbin/start hadoop-hdfs-namenode
ssh -i <key.pem> <slave-hostname1> "sudo /sbin/restart  hadoop-hdfs-datanode"
ssh -i <key.pem> <slave-hostname2> "sudo /sbin/restart  hadoop-hdfs-datanode"
ssh -i <key.pem> <slave-hostname3> "sudo /sbin/restart  hadoop-hdfs-datanode"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually restart the cluster. This can be either performed manually or using a simple shell script.

1) Get the list of hostnames or ipaddress of all the nodes,

2) ssh into the node using the key

3) Restart the required service.

If you are good in programming, you can create a general utility that will get the list of ipaddress of all the nodes corresponding to an EMR by using the cluster id and perform the service restart in individual nodes.

Otherwise, get the hostname or ipaddress of all the nodes manually and create a script like the below one and execute from the master node

```
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode restart
ssh -i <key.pem> <hostname1> "sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode restart"
ssh -i <key.pem> <hostname2> "sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode restart"
ssh -i <key.pem> <hostname3> "sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode restart"
```

Comment: With version 4.x in EMR, it seems that the namenode and datanode services are not running under /etc/init.d and hence cannot be started in the above way.

Comment: On EMR 4 : ```sudo restart hadoop-hdfs-namenode```

Comment: @Tony sudo restart hadoop-hdfs-datanode does not work? How to restart datanodes  EMR4

Answer (score 0):

On EMR 5.x this is what I used:

1. Copy PEM file to your head node and set these values:

   ```
   CLUSTER_ID="j-XXXXXXXXXXX"
   IDENT="cluster.pem"
   ```
2. Run this:

   ```
   nodes=$(aws emr list-instances \
       --cluster-id $ \
       --instance-group-types CORE \
       --instance-states RUNNING \
       --output text \
       --query "Instances[*].PublicDnsName" )

   for node in nodes; do
       ssh -i $IDENT \
           -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
           -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
           $node "sudo stop hadoop-hdfs-datanode; sudo start hadoop-hdfs-datanode"
   done
   ```